# Javascript How to get the common elements inside two while loops

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare the common element of the output of two while loops:

```
while (parseInt(n1) <= parseInt(max)) {
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML += parseInt(n1) + ",";
    n1 = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(i1);
}

while(parseInt(n2) <= parseInt(max)){
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML += parseInt(n2) + ",";
    n2 = parseInt(n2) + parseInt(i2);
}
```

Meaning, if the out put the while loop #1 is: 1,3,**5**,7,9,11,**13**

and the output of while loop #2 is: 4,8,**5**,12,**13**

Then it should return a value of: **5,13**

I am thinking of making the output as an array but I dont know how since I can not make the output of the while loop as a variable.
Thank you very much!

Here's my code:

```js
    
        function calculate() {
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "";
            let n1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
            let i1 = document.getElementById("increment1").value;
            let n2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
            let i2 = document.getElementById("increment2").value;
            let max = document.getElementById("maximum").value;
            while (parseInt(n1) <= parseInt(max)) {
                document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML += parseInt(n1) + ",";
                n1 = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(i1);
            }
    
            while(parseInt(n2) <= parseInt(max)){
                document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML += parseInt(n2) + ",";
                n2 = parseInt(n2) + parseInt(i2);
            }
    
        }
```

```html
    Maximum Range:<input type="number" id="maximum"> <br><br>
    
    number 1: <input type="number" id="number1"> <br>
    increment 1: <input type="number" id="increment1">
    
    <br><br>
    
    <h3>Compare it with:</h3>
    
    number 2: <input type="number" id="number2"> <br>
    increment 2: <input type="number" id="increment2">
    
    <br><br>
    
    <button onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button> <hr>
    
    <strong>Results:</strong>
    <p id="result1"></p>
    <p id="result2"></p>
```

edit:
I tried this code to compare the similarities inside the while loop, but still did not work.:

```
    function commonElementsOfArray(arr1, arr2) {
        return arr1.filter(function (n) {
            return arr2.indexOf(n) !== -1;
        });
    }

    function compareArrays() {
        let string1 = document.getElementById("result1");
        let string2 = document.getElementById("result2");
alert(string1);
        let string1Arr = string1.split(",");
        let string2Arr = string2.split(",");

        let commonString = commonElementsOfArray(string1Arr, string2Arr);
        document.getElementById("compareResults").innerHTML = commonString;
}
```

Comment: please consider sharing html/css/js code in a snippet (`Ctrl + M`)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the arrays as sets and find the intersection this way:

```
const array1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13];
const array2 = [4, 8, 5, 12, 13];

const set1 = new Set(array1);
const set2 = new Set(array2);
const intersection = [...set1].filter((x) => set2.has(x));

console.log(intersection);
```

This will output:

```
[ 5, 13 ]
```

Comment: Thank you, but the numbers are generated using while loop. And those are strings not array.

Comment: Can you edit with the sample output of each while loop?

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*Getting common ELements*/
let a = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13];
let b = [4,8,5,12,13];
let common = a.filter(e1 => b.includes(e1)) //if current element of a is found in array b
console.log(common);

/*Showing Common ELements in HTML*/
let ele = document.getElementsByClassName('result')[0];
ele.innerHTML = common.join(', ');
```

```html
<document>
  <body>
    <div class="result"></div>
  </body>
</document>
```

Comment: I think you could also simplify this using `includes`, as follows: `let common = a.filter(e1 => b.includes(e1))` If the results need to be unique, you can use lodash, or `let common = Array.from(new Set(a.filter(e1 => b.includes(e1))))`

Comment: Thank you, but the numbers are generated using while loop. And those are strings not array.

Answer (score 0):

Just a draft, but you may try this:

```js
const set1 = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10];
const set2 = [3, 5, 7, 10, 15];
//Should get [3, 10]

//Using filter
function calcWithFilter(s1, s2) {
  return [...new Set(s1)].filter(function (n) {
    return s2.includes(n);
  });
}

//Using loops
function calcWithLoops(s1, s2) {
  let temp = [];
  for (let num of new Set(s1)) {
    if (s2.includes(num)) {
      temp.push(num);
    }
  }
  return temp;
}

console.log(calcWithFilter(set1, set2));
console.log(calcWithLoops(set1, set2));
```